# List of mathematicians

Tags: random, curated-data, entity

How to make a list of mathematicians by using *Mathematica*?

There are  $284387$ person entity in *Mathematica*, but I need only mathematician entity

[image]

I tried something like this

```
EntityList[EntityClass["Person", "Mathematician"]]
```

but it doesn't work.

Can we use  `RandomEntity`?

Comment: You may try `EntityValue[#, EntityProperty["Person", "MathematicalAchievements"]] & /@ EntityList["Person"] // DeleteMissing`, but it would be incredibly slooooooow.

Comment: Usually this would be achieved with an *implicit entity*, like this `EntityList@EntityClass["Person", {EntityProperty["Person", "Occupation"] -> "mathematician"}]` but *Mathematica* complains that this is too slow in this case.

Comment: There is also a list [here](https://www.12000.org/my_notes/science_time_line/) of famous mathematicians. Not sure what it is based on, but there are many there listed.

Answer (score 3):

Too long for a comment:

List entries from [Hundred Greatest Mathematicians of the Past](https://fabpedigree.com/james/greatmm.htm). Some of these required manual search/insertion using the desktop (`==`) Wolfram search.

I couldn't get {"Archytas of Tarentum", "Panini of Shalatula"} to be recognized through the `Entity` system}. The last one "Thales" is not a mathematician but a "philosopher" from antiquity.

```
list0100100 = {Entity["Person", "IsaacNewton::bhz5x"], 
  Entity["Person", "Archimedes::29f2h"], 
  Entity["Person", "CarlFriedrichGauss::4vctc"], 
  Entity["Person", "LeonhardEuler::39r8r"], 
  Entity["Person", "BernhardRiemann::272q7"], 
  Entity["Person", "DavidHilbert::8r974"], 
  Entity["Person", "Joseph-LouisLagrange::77tv7"], 
  Entity["Person", "Euclid::2m284"], 
  Entity["Person", "AlexanderGrothendieck::853tv"], 
  Entity["Person", "GottfriedLeibniz::s2hc2"], 
  Entity["Person", "JohnVonNeumann::mb6vy"], 
  Entity["Person", "HenriPoincare::876r2"], 
  Entity["Person", "EvaristeGalois::573r9"], 
  Entity["Person", "SrinivasaAiyangarRamanujan::cx83t"], 
  Entity["Person", "PierreDeFermat::p9q8b"], 
  Entity["Person", "HermannWeyl::n3x53"], 
  Entity["Person", "KarlWeierstrass::v982v"], 
  Entity["Person", "Brahmagupta::46by5"], 
  Entity["Person", "NielsHenrikAbel::66z74"], 
  Entity["Person", "ReneDescartes::x2xj8"], 
  Entity["Person", "GeorgCantor::yw4tz"], 
  Entity["Person", "EmmyAmalieNoether::442v8"], 
  Entity["Person", "LejeuneDirichlet::457j9"], 
  Entity["Person", "Pythagoras::ksw9v"], 
  Entity["Person", "MuhammadIbnMusaAl-Khwarizmi::sy4kd"], 
  Entity["Person", "CarlLudwigSiegel::9568x"], 
  Entity["Person", "Augustin-LouisCauchy::ycm4g"], 
  Entity["Person", "ArthurCayley::pdr6d"], 
  Entity["Person", "BillyHamilton::736n3"], 
  Entity["Person", "ApolloniusOfPerga::95k59"], 
  Entity["Person", "CharlesHermite::w53k5"], 
  Entity["Person", "LeonardoFibonacci::qwrh8"], 
  Entity["Person", "CarlJacobi::s2884"], 
  Entity["Person", "Diophantus::b7ysk"], 
  Entity["Person", "Pierre-SimonLaplace::636r8"], 
  Entity["Person", "ElieJosephCartan::2pp38"], 
  Entity["Person", "Aryabhata::nc44d"], 
  Entity["Person", "JohannesKepler::82d83"], 
  Entity["Person", "AndreyNikolaevichKolmogorov::84q87"], 
  Entity["Person", "GiuseppePeano::5fw63"], 
  Entity["Person", "FelixKlein::zpw54"], 
  Entity["Person", "EmileBorel::3dtbs"], 
  Entity["Person", "RichardDedekind::jcjv2"], 
  Entity["Person", "BhaskaraII::v2b43"], 
  Entity["Person", "KurtGodel::h4724"], 
  Entity["Person", "GodfreyHaroldHardy::56bj6"], 
  Entity["Person", "Hipparchus::tcwn5"], 
  Entity["Person", "Alhazen::24s2k"], 
  Entity["Person", "MariusSophusLie::2fhh8"], 
  Entity["Person", "BlaisePascal::6q6n4"], 
  Entity["Person", "JuliusPlucker::x89b8"], 
  Entity["Person", "StefanBanach::4574t"], 
  Entity["Person", "JacobBernoulli::gpbw5"], 
  Entity["Person", "AndreWeil::9zjjy"], 
  Entity["Person", "GottlobFrege::xqfg7"], 
  Entity["Person", "FerdinandGottholdMaxEisenstein::n7kgn"], 
  Entity["Person", "Jean-PierreSerre::pmg5z"], 
  Entity["Person", "JeanLeRondDAlembert::gvkt7"], 
  Entity["Person", "MichaelFrancisAtiyah::kppw9"], 
  Entity["Person", "AlfredTarski::xvkn2"], 
  Entity["Person", "JakobSteiner::85m25"], 
  Entity["Person", "ChristiaanHuygens::9523h"], 
  Entity["Person", "FrancoisViete::32j96"], 
  Entity["Person", "AtleSelberg::q87d5"], 
  Entity["Person", "JacquesHadamard::q46r3"], 
  Entity["Person", "JosephLiouville::3z25x"], 
  Entity["Person", "Jean-Baptiste-JosephFourier::kcgs4"], 
  Entity["Person", "MarieEnnemondCamilleJordan::jnsh8"], 
  Entity["Person", "AlbertEinstein::6tb7g"], 
  Entity["Person", "JamesClerkMaxwell::8hrvp"], 
  Entity["Person", "GirolamoCardano::3r45m"], 
  Entity["Person", "Aristotle::72d96"], 
  Entity["Person", "GalileoGalilei::rxsr7"], 
  Entity["Person", "EudoxusOfCnidus::jw3vt"], 
  Entity["Person", "IsraelGelfand::6z89t"], 
  Entity["Person", "GeorgePolya::3xr7y"], 
  Entity["Person", "FelixHausdorff::4f66d"], 
  Entity["Person", "HermannGrassmann::d3y79"], 
  Entity["Person", "AlanTuring::2f4s8"], 
  Entity["Person", "JohannLambert::b9293"], 
  Entity["Person", "JohnEdensorLittlewood::jd5z3"], 
  Entity["Person", "JohnForbesNashJr::xqg7w"], 
  Entity["Person", "LEJBrouwer::v7335"], 
  Entity["Person", "BonaventuraFrancescoCavalieri::246t8"], 
  Entity["Person", "ErnstEduardKummer::5n86b"], 
  Entity["Person", "Shiing-shenChern::6f845"], 
  Entity["Person", "JamesJosephSylvester::fp694"], 
  Entity["Person", "JohannBernoulli::772rn"], 
  Entity["Person", "GeorgeDavidBirkhoff::mw8h8"], 
  Entity["Person", "GaspardMonge::56frg"], 
  Entity["Person", "Henri-LeonLebesgue::m48s3"], 
  Entity["Person", "AndreyMarkov::465hg"], 
  Entity["Person", "PafnutyLvovichChebyshev::874vh"], 
  Entity["Person", "OmarKhayyam::rbf9g"], 
  Entity["Person", "JohnWallis::738ny"], 
  Entity["Person", "Jean-VictorPoncelet::d628s"], 
  Entity["Person", "Adrien-MarieLegendre::224bz"], 
  Entity["Person", "Thales::535t4"]}
```

**EDIT**

I will leave the previous list unmodified. Following is a list of 237 renowned mathematicians and philosophers from [The 200 Greatest Mathematicians of All Time](https://fabpedigree.com/james/gmat200.htm#Napier) that I could verify or extract from the `Entity` system.

```
mmlist = {Entity["Person", "IsaacNewton::bhz5x"], 
  Entity["Person", "Archimedes::29f2h"], 
  Entity["Person", "CarlFriedrichGauss::4vctc"], 
  Entity["Person", "LeonhardEuler::39r8r"], 
  Entity["Person", "BernhardRiemann::272q7"], 
  Entity["Person", "DavidHilbert::8r974"], 
  Entity["Person", "Joseph-LouisLagrange::77tv7"], 
  Entity["Person", "Euclid::2m284"], 
  Entity["Person", "AlexanderGrothendieck::853tv"], 
  Entity["Person", "GottfriedLeibniz::s2hc2"], 
  Entity["Person", "JohnVonNeumann::mb6vy"], 
  Entity["Person", "HenriPoincare::876r2"], 
  Entity["Person", "EvaristeGalois::573r9"], 
  Entity["Person", "SrinivasaAiyangarRamanujan::cx83t"], 
  Entity["Person", "PierreDeFermat::p9q8b"], 
  Entity["Person", "HermannWeyl::n3x53"], 
  Entity["Person", "Brahmagupta::46by5"], 
  Entity["Person", "NielsHenrikAbel::66z74"], 
  Entity["Person", "ReneDescartes::x2xj8"], 
  Entity["Person", "GeorgCantor::yw4tz"], 
  Entity["Person", "EmmyAmalieNoether::442v8"], 
  Entity["Person", "Pythagoras::ksw9v"], 
  Entity["Person", "MuhammadIbnMusaAl-Khwarizmi::sy4kd"], 
  Entity["Person", "CarlLudwigSiegel::9568x"], 
  Entity["Person", "Augustin-LouisCauchy::ycm4g"], 
  Entity["Person", "ArthurCayley::pdr6d"], 
  Entity["Person", "BillyHamilton::736n3"], 
  Entity["Person", "ApolloniusOfPerga::95k59"], 
  Entity["Person", "CharlesHermite::w53k5"], 
  Entity["Person", "CarlJacobi::s2884"], 
  Entity["Person", "Diophantus::b7ysk"], 
  Entity["Person", "Pierre-SimonLaplace::636r8"], 
  Entity["Person", "ElieJosephCartan::2pp38"], 
  Entity["Person", "Aryabhata::nc44d"], 
  Entity["Person", "JohannesKepler::82d83"], 
  Entity["Person", "AndreyNikolaevichKolmogorov::84q87"], 
  Entity["Person", "GiuseppePeano::5fw63"], 
  Entity["Person", "FelixKlein::zpw54"], 
  Entity["Person", "RichardDedekind::jcjv2"], 
  Entity["Person", "KurtGodel::h4724"], 
  Entity["Person", "GodfreyHaroldHardy::56bj6"], 
  Entity["Person", "Hipparchus::tcwn5"], 
  Entity["Person", "Alhazen::24s2k"], 
  Entity["Person", "MariusSophusLie::2fhh8"], 
  Entity["Person", "BlaisePascal::6q6n4"], 
  Entity["Person", "JuliusPlucker::x89b8"], 
  Entity["Person", "StefanBanach::4574t"], 
  Entity["Person", "JacobBernoulli::gpbw5"], 
  Entity["Person", "AndreWeil::9zjjy"], 
  Entity["Person", "GottlobFrege::xqfg7"], 
  Entity["Person", "Jean-PierreSerre::pmg5z"], 
  Entity["Person", "JeanLeRondDAlembert::gvkt7"], 
  Entity["Person", "MichaelFrancisAtiyah::kppw9"], 
  Entity["Person", "AlfredTarski::xvkn2"], 
  Entity["Person", "JakobSteiner::85m25"], 
  Entity["Person", "ChristiaanHuygens::9523h"], 
  Entity["Person", "FrancoisViete::32j96"], 
  Entity["Person", "AtleSelberg::q87d5"], 
  Entity["Person", "JacquesHadamard::q46r3"], 
  Entity["Person", "JosephLiouville::3z25x"], 
  Entity["Person", "Jean-Baptiste-JosephFourier::kcgs4"], 
  Entity["Person", "AlbertEinstein::6tb7g"], 
  Entity["Person", "JamesClerkMaxwell::8hrvp"], 
  Entity["Person", "GirolamoCardano::3r45m"], 
  Entity["Person", "Aristotle::72d96"], 
  Entity["Person", "GalileoGalilei::rxsr7"], 
  Entity["Person", "EudoxusOfCnidus::jw3vt"], 
  Entity["Person", "IsraelGelfand::6z89t"], 
  Entity["Person", "GeorgePolya::3xr7y"], 
  Entity["Person", "FelixHausdorff::4f66d"], 
  Entity["Person", "HermannGrassmann::d3y79"], 
  Entity["Person", "AlanTuring::2f4s8"], 
  Entity["Person", "JohannLambert::b9293"], 
  Entity["Person", "JohnEdensorLittlewood::jd5z3"], 
  Entity["Person", "LEJBrouwer::v7335"], 
  Entity["Person", "BonaventuraFrancescoCavalieri::246t8"], 
  Entity["Person", "ErnstEduardKummer::5n86b"], 
  Entity["Person", "Shiing-shenChern::6f845"], 
  Entity["Person", "JamesJosephSylvester::fp694"], 
  Entity["Person", "JohannBernoulli::772rn"], 
  Entity["Person", "GeorgeDavidBirkhoff::mw8h8"], 
  Entity["Person", "GaspardMonge::56frg"], 
  Entity["Person", "Henri-LeonLebesgue::m48s3"], 
  Entity["Person", "AndreyMarkov::465hg"], 
  Entity["Person", "PafnutyLvovichChebyshev::874vh"], 
  Entity["Person", "JohnWallis::738ny"], 
  Entity["Person", "Jean-VictorPoncelet::d628s"], 
  Entity["Person", "Adrien-MarieLegendre::224bz"], 
  Entity["Person", "Thales::535t4"], 
  Entity["Person", "DanielBernoulli::3zt83"], 
  Entity["Person", "GastonJulia::7gzjs"], 
  Entity["Person", "SimonStevin::77mtq"], 
  Entity["Person", "SofiaKovalevskaya::5p839"], 
  Entity["Person", "Jean-GastonDarboux::4xgpp"], 
  Entity["Person", "MikhailLeonidovichGromov::884t8"], 
  Entity["Person", "PaulJosephCohen::sv53f"], 
  Entity["Person", "JohnWillardMilnor::j547m"], 
  Entity["Person", "RobertPhelanLanglands::5654c"], 
  Entity["Person", "JohnConway::85n74"], 
  Entity["Person", "PierreReneDeligne::2n43f"], 
  Entity["Person", "WilliamPaulThurston::m38w7"], 
  Entity["Person", "EdwardWitten::26k3t"], 
  Entity["Person", "SaharonShelah::nf7p4"], 
  Entity["Person", "TerenceTao::p7jdj"], 
  Entity["Person", "JohnGriggsThompson::wcmc8"], 
  Entity["Person", "SimonKirwanDonaldson::k6nb2"], 
  Entity["Person", "VladimirArnold::8wvrn"], 
  Entity["Person", "StephenSmale::tm48g"], 
  Entity["Person", "TimothyGowers::w7p69"], 
  Entity["Person", "Simeon-DenisPoisson::r7bbr"], 
  Entity["Person", "LarsValerianAhlfors::98c4b"], 
  Entity["Person", "Al-SabiThabitIbnQurraAl-Harrani::yz652"], 
  Entity["Person", "NasirAl-DinAl-Tusi::h4k7r"], 
  Entity["Person", "PaulErdos::xxcc4"], 
  Entity["Person", "EmilArtin::684kc"], 
  Entity["Person", "HermannMinkowski::8x4m9"], 
  Entity["Person", "LeopoldKronecker::2z285"], 
  Entity["Person", "WilliamKingdonClifford::cd2w4"], 
  Entity["Person", "TullioLevi-Civita::m6d68"], 
  Entity["Person", "Pappus::zbtf6"], 
  Entity["Person", "LiuHui::y76y9"], 
  Entity["Person", "JamesGregory::b2mzy"], 
  Entity["Person", "JohnTorrenceTate::59t95"], 
  Entity["Person", "PeterDavidLax::ns7j7"], 
  Entity["Person", "AlexisClaudeClairaut::ncg65"], 
  Entity["Person", "ZhuShijie::8r45r"], 
  Entity["Person", "ColinMaclaurin::9x7rg"], 
  Entity["Person", "GeorgeBoole::p56jt"], 
  Entity["Person", "HenriCartan::z7728"], 
  Entity["Person", "NorbertWiener::nc8r9"], 
  Entity["Person", "OliverHeaviside::62ww4"], 
  Entity["Person", "HenryJohnStephenSmith::f962b"], 
  Entity["Person", "RafaelBombelli::769t7"], 
  Entity["Person", "RudolfFriedrichAlfredClebsch::5876c"], 
  Entity["Person", "PaulDirac::9r2f7"], 
  Entity["Person", "SamuelEilenberg::72q82"], 
  Entity["Person", "JWillardGibbs::n336f"], 
  Entity["Person", "EdmundGeorgHermannLandau::9j3k4"], 
  Entity["Person", "LaszloLovasz::r639j"], 
  Entity["Person", "MadhavaOfSangamagrama::944x9"], 
  Entity["Person", "LouisNirenberg::84t6x"], 
  Entity["Person", "RogerPenrose::4653p"], 
  Entity["Person", "LevSemenovichPontryagin::4rggz"], 
  Entity["Person", "WaclawSierpinski::52f52"], 
  Entity["Person", "IsadoreManuelSinger::j4tyn"], 
  Entity["Person", "ThoralfAlbertSkolem::q3zsh"], 
  Entity["Person", "EndreSzemeredi::4t95j"], 
  Entity["Person", "KarenKeskullaUhlenbeck::y2674"], 
  Entity["Person", "OswaldVeblen::9z5j7"], 
  Entity["Person", "Shing-TungYau::6y3d9"], 
  Entity["Person", "OscarZariski::6hk6z"], 
  Entity["Person", "GirardDesargues::y296j"], 
  Entity["Person", "WilliamVallanceDouglasHodge::z6549"], 
  Entity["Person", "VaughanFRJones::24k8z"], 
  Entity["Person", "KunihikoKodaira::c24q9"], 
  Entity["Person", "SolomonLefschetz::4hd2w"], 
  Entity["Person", "LeonardoDaVinci::47w36"], 
  Entity["Person", "JeanLeray::zd336"], 
  Entity["Person", "AbrahamDeMoivre::gby76"], 
  Entity["Person", "DavidBryantMumford::d44k2"], 
  Entity["Person", "GrigoriPerelman::9328x"], 
  Entity["Person", "Ptolemy::y9827"], 
  Entity["Person", "ClaudeShannon::zyv5g"], 
  Entity["Person", "BrookTaylor::3w2bv"], 
  Entity["Person", "JacquesTits::4sy28"], 
  Entity["Person", "EvangelistaTorricelli::7bbd3"], 
  Entity["Person", "AndrewWiles::62p4d"], 
  Entity["Person", "ErnstFriedrichFerdinandZermelo::95sgs"], 
  Entity["Person", "AlanBaker::8s84y"], 
  Entity["Person", "EnricoBombieri::74p74"], 
  Entity["Person", "RaoulBott::x322z"], 
  Entity["Person", "JeanBourgain::b72rs"], 
  Entity["Person", "AlainConnes::9ypxr"], 
  Entity["Person", "GerdFaltings::3278m"], 
  Entity["Person", "CharlesLouisFefferman::3d354"], 
  Entity["Person", "PhillipAugustusGriffiths::7h42z"], 
  Entity["Person", "FriedrichErnstPeterHirzebruch::62k25"], 
  Entity["Person", "MaximKontsevich::v7j74"], 
  Entity["Person", "EmilArtin::684kc"], 
  Entity["Person", "BenoitMandelbrot::jc4v3"], 
  Entity["Person", "YuriVladimirovichMatiyasevich::qr758"], 
  Entity["Person", "BarryCharlesMazur::5749k"], 
  Entity["Person", "YvesMeyer::7m995"], 
  Entity["Person", "SergeyNovikov::223q4"], 
  Entity["Person", "DanielGrayQuillen::3v7y2"], 
  Entity["Person", "JuliaHallBowmanRobinson::t8m7w"], 
  Entity["Person", "KlausFriedrichRoth::82v7b"], 
  Entity["Person", "GoroShimura::558n3"], 
  Entity["Person", "EliasMStein::47x56"], 
  Entity["Person", "SRSrinivasaVaradhan::5p288"], 
  Entity["Person", "WendelinWerner::7bdt4"], 
  Entity["Person", "HasslerWhitney::y4n93"], 
  Entity["Person", "GhiyathAl-DinJamshidMasudAl-Kashi::jmg5d"], 
  Entity["Person", "EugenioBeltrami::vkh96"], 
  Entity["Person", "AbramSamoilovitchBesicovitch::9gwf7"], 
  Entity["Person", "AntonioLuigiGaudenzioGiuseppeCremona::m6754"], 
  Entity["Person", "Democritus::c6t36"], 
  Entity["Person", "Eratosthenes::333v2"], 
  Entity["Person", "HeroOfAlexandria::k5pfc"], 
  Entity["Person", "AleksandrYakovlevichKhinchin::m4292"], 
  Entity["Person", "KazimierzKuratowski::693k8"], 
  Entity["Person", "QinJiushao::394c9"], 
  Entity["Person", "GillesPersonneDeRoberval::6tczb"], 
  Entity["Person", "ThomasJanStieltjes::38d82"], 
  Entity["Person", "TeijiTakagi::8hqhk"], 
  Entity["Person", "KarlWeierstrass::v982v"], 
  Entity["Person", "LeonardoFibonacci::qwrh8"], 
  Entity["Person", "EmileBorel::3dtbs"], 
  Entity["Person", "FerdinandGottholdMaxEisenstein::n7kgn"], 
  Entity["Person", "MarieEnnemondCamilleJordan::jnsh8"], 
  Entity["Person", "JohnForbesNashJr::xqg7w"], 
  Entity["Person", "OmarKhayyam::rbf9g"], 
  Entity["Person", "LennartAxelEdvardCarleson::j9b93"], 
  Entity["Person", "GeorgFrobenius::4y339"], 
  Entity["Person", "AugustMobius::6962p"], 
  Entity["Person", "JohannMullerRegiomontanus::6d728"], 
  Entity["Person", "MichelChasles::68x52"], 
  Entity["Person", "MauriceFrechet::v329d"], 
  Entity["Person", "LarsHormander::4853f"], 
  Entity["Person", "GrigoryMargulis::ggg9d"], 
  Entity["Person", "DennisSullivan::m67tw"], 
  Entity["Person", "IvanMatveyevichVinogradov::wxjv5"], 
  Entity["Person", "JeanI::j2f52"], 
  Entity["Person", "JeanAlexandreEugeneDieudonne::4654w"], 
  Entity["Person", "YuriIvanovichManin::bm4p7"], 
  Entity["Person", "CharlesFrancoisSturm::p56x4"], 
  Entity["Person", "VitoVolterra::2295s"], 
  Entity["Person", "LejeuneDirichlet::457j9"], 
  Entity["Person", "BhaskaraII::v2b43"], 
  Entity["Person", "NikolaiLobachevsky::d4zns"], 
  Entity["Person", "JohnNapier::3b49c"], 
  Entity["Person", "Al-Kindi::mh67c"], 
  Entity["Person", "Hippocrates::69x79"], 
  Entity["Person", "SophieGermain::7nq45"], 
  Entity["Person", "Plato::j2247"], 
  Entity["Person", "Avicenna::2rvbd"], 
  Entity["Person", "NicholasOfCusa::2t4gk"]}
```